# Javascript / jQuery HTML5 Video - catch net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR with listener

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm loading multiple videos but sometimes some of them aren't loaded and I get the error:

```
net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I tried to catch it like this:

```
    const videoElement = $('#' + videoID);
    
    videoElement.get(0).addEventListener('loadeddata', (e) => {
        log("video loaded");
    });

    videoElement.get(0).addEventListener('error', (e) => {
        log("video load failed");       
    });
```

so I can retry to load the video but it's not working, `video load failed` isn't printed out.

So is there a way to do that? The videos are 100% there and the url is correct

Comment: Are you mixing HTTP and HTTPS links? All your links should ideally be HTTPS to avoid net security and net protocol errors. Anyways it seems you found a fix, so that should help to solve error for others too..

Comment: Nope, it just happens randomly to different videos, probably because I'm loading up to 10 videos at the same time

Comment: Loading multiple files alone should not trigger SSL (secure sockets layer) error. Maybe you'll get a socket error if one connection drops. I could try loading many videos at once but I bet it won't recreate your problem on my computer. If you still need an answer either **(1)** Show a demo link of your problem in action for others to check/advise, **(2)** Mention if any extra frameworks like React are involved in unseen code. **(3)** Listen for video events like _`stalled`_ or _`aborted`_ to know when a loading fail happens...

Comment: But this is the error I get for the videos that aren't loaded, I know it doesn't make much sense but that's the case. "Listen for video events like stalled or aborted" but the error listener in my answer already catch when a video doesn't load, why would I need that? But anyway please give an example as answer and when it works I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working solution for me:

```
videoElement.get(0).addEventListener('error', function(event) { 
    log("got it"); 
}, true);
```